# String representation of an object... verbose vs hexadecimal

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on a program where I have to read a file and store the name of the  prize and the price of it. I am trying to print out the array that I have information stored on but it is instead printing out the hexadecimal code. How can I fix this so that the array has the correct name and price stored on it? Here is my code:

```
public class PrizeGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Prize[] prizes = new Prize[50];

        Random random = new Random();

        try {
            Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File("prizeList.txt"));

            int count = 0;
            while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String fileLine = fileScanner.nextLine();
                String[] splitLine = fileLine.split("\t");
                if (splitLine.length == 2) {
                    prizes[count] = new Prize(splitLine[0], Integer.parseInt(splitLine[1]));

                    count++;
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < prizes.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(prizes[i]);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error reading file");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my code for prize():

```
 public class Prize {

  String name;
  int price;


  public Prize(String name, int price){
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
  }


  public String getName()
  {
    return name;
  }

  public int getPrice()
  {
    return price;
  }

  public void setName(String name)
  {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public void setPrice(int price)
  {
    this.price = price;
  }




 }
```

Comment: Please show us your implementation of `Prize`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `toString` method to Prize:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
  return this.name + " " + this.price;
}
```

**or** instead of:

```
System.out.println(prizes[i]);
```

write

```
System.out.println(prizes[i].getName() + " " + prizes[i].getPrice());
```

Comment: Thank you. I can store everything and print out the variable now. However, how could I print out just the text of a single instance or just the price? When I try to do this outside of the while loop, it says that the SplitLine cannot be resolved to a variable. Thank you again.

Comment: Nevermind. your edits helped me figure it out. Thank you.

Comment: This is because `splitLine` is declared inside a while loop. If you declare it immediately before this loop, it will be visible after this loop.